# He {speaks/has spoken} German since a long time

Tags: time, present-vs-perfect

If a non-native speaker was to say

> He speaks German since a long time.

How would you correct the sentence and what tense would you say he is trying to speak in?

Answer (score 4):

The sentence as written uses the verb *speak* in Present Indefinite Tense.  What tense to use depends on what exactly the statement is trying to convey.  It is a bit difficult to discern the intended meaning from the sentence written.

If the non-native speaker wants to say that "*he*" is capable of expressing himself in German, and that ability became evident some (long) time ago, then I'd say

> He **has spoken** German for a long time.

Another possible form has two clauses connected by a conjunction 'and':

> He **speaks** German, and *has* for a long time.

If the speaker wants to say that "*he*" uses German ***now*** and that action started some (long) time ago, then Present Perfect Continuous is better:

> He **has been speaking** German for a long time.

Comment: +1 I particularly like the last one; it suggests a filibuster in the Bundestag. :)

Answer (score 1):

> > He speaks German since a long time.

**The present perfect**

When we want to show that an activity or situation started in the past and is continuing now, we use a present perfect construction, not the present simple:

- *I work here for four years. (wrong - might possibly refer to the future, but cannot refer to the past continuing into the present)
- *I worked here for four years. (wrong - it implies that this four years is entirely in the past).
- I have worked here for four years. (good)

***For*** **and** ***since***

The Original Poster's example uses *since* with a period of time. This is an easy mistake to make. We usually use *since* with a ***point*** in time when we use the present perfect. Here are some potential points in time we can use with the present perfect:

- Tuesday
- 1pm
- 1984

A period of time is different from a point in time. Periods have length. *Three o'clock* has no length. *Three hours* has length. It's three hours long! When we want to use the present perfect with a ***period*** of time, we need to use the preposition *for*. Here are some more examples of periods of time:

- three days
- two years
- five minutes
- ages
- a while

We can change a period of time into a point in time by adding the word *ago*:

- three days ago
- five years ago

Some examples of the present perfect with points:

- I've been vegetarian **since** 1995.
- She hasn't been seen **since** Wednesday evening.
- Bob hasn't eaten **since** dinnertime.

Some examples of the present perfect with periods:

- I've been vegetarian for ten years.
- She hasn't been seen for five days.
- Bob hasn't eaten for ages.

**The Original Poster's Question**

The man's speaking German started in the past and is continuing now. So we need a present perfect construction. We could choose either a continuous perfect or just a plain present perfect. *A long time* is a period, not a point, so we have a choice. We can use the preposition *for*, or we could change the phrase to *a long time ago:

**Simple**

> 1. He's spoken German for a long time.
> 2. He's spoken German since a long time ago.

**Continuous**

> 3. He's been speaking German for a long time
> 4. He's been speaking German since a long time ago.

My favourite choice would be (3). Both the continuous aspect and the preposition *for* emphasise the duration of the activity, in my opinion.

Comment: +1. And to spice things up, we can say: "He has spoken German since *he was a kid*." or "... since childhood".